# Codewars Buddy Pairs Kata Optimize Python Solution

Tags: python, algorithm

Here is the kata link: https://www.codewars.com/kata/59ccf051dcc4050f7800008f/shell

> Buddy pairs You know what divisors of a number are. The divisors of a
> positive integer n are said to be proper when you consider only the
> divisors other than n itself. In the following description, divisors
> will mean proper divisors. For example for 100 they are 1, 2, 4, 5,
> 10, 20, 25, and 50.
>
> Let s(n) be the sum of these proper divisors of n. Call buddy two
> positive integers such that the sum of the proper divisors of each
> number is one more than the other number:
>
> (n, m) are a pair of buddy if s(m) = n + 1 and s(n) = m + 1
>
> For example 48 & 75 is such a pair:
>
> Divisors of 48 are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 24 --> sum: 76 = 75 + 1
> Divisors of 75 are: 1, 3, 5, 15, 25 --> sum: 49 = 48 + 1 Task Given
> two positive integers start and limit, the function buddy(start,
> limit) should return the first pair (n m) of buddy pairs such that n
> (positive integer) is between start (inclusive) and limit (inclusive);
> m can be greater than limit and has to be greater than n
>
> If there is no buddy pair satisfying the conditions, then return
> "Nothing" or (for Go lang) nil or (for Dart) null; (for Lua, Pascal,
> Perl) [-1, -1].

> test.assert_equals(buddy(10, 50), [48, 75])

> test.assert_equals(buddy(2177, 4357), "Nothing")

> test.assert_equals(buddy(57345, 90061), [62744, 75495])

> test.assert_equals(buddy(1071625, 1103735), [1081184, 1331967])

Here is my solution but it is taking too much time I'm getting `Execution Timed Out` error:

```
def sum_divisors(num):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            sum += i

    return sum


def buddy(start, limit):
    for i in range(start, limit + 1):
        sum = sum_divisors(i)
        sum_minus_one = sum_divisors(sum - 1)

        if start > sum - 1:
            continue

        if i == (sum_minus_one - 1):
            return [i, sum - 1]

    return "Nothing"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fast way to find the sum of a number's divisors, based on its prime factorization:

```
from math import isqrt

def sum_of_divisors(n):
    result = 1
    div = 1
    while True:
        for div in range(div + 1, isqrt(n) + 1):
            if not n % div:
                mul = 1
                while not n % div:
                    n //= div
                    mul = 1 + mul * div
                result *= mul
                break
        else:
            if n > 1:
                result *= 1 + n
            return result
```

Consider for example n=100. Divisors are products of the prime factors, for example the divisor 50 is 2×5².

Initially known prime factors: None
Possible products of prime factors: Just the empty product, which has value 1.
Sum of those products: 1

After finding prime factor 2 (twice):
Possible products: The previous products multiplied by 2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>1</sup> or 2<sup>2</sup>.
Sum of the products: The previous sum multiplied by (1+2+4), i.e., 1×7=7.

After finding prime factor 5 (twice):
Possible products: The previous products multiplied by 5<sup>0</sup>, 5<sup>1</sup> or 5<sup>2</sup>.
Sum of the products: The previous sum multiplied by (1+5+25), i.e., 7×31=217.

If you subtract n itself, you get 117, which is also the sum of 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, and 50 (the list of proper divisors stated in the task description).

And my `buddy` function using the above:

```
def buddy(start, limit):
    def s(n):
        return sum_of_divisors(n) - n
    for n in range(start, limit + 1):
        m = s(n) - 1
        if m > n and s(m) == n + 1:
            return [n, m]
    return 'Nothing'
```

Comparing mine with gimix's on the largest case from Codewars, `buddy(145_809_719, 145_812_719)`:

```
Kelly:  0.84 seconds
gimix: 10.57 seconds
```

Yours takes ~18 seconds for `buddy(145_811_219, 145_811_219`, which is only the median candidate of the 3001. If that's representative, then it would take ~15 hours for all 3001.

Answer (score 1):

Some optimizations:

To find the sum of divisors:

- 1 is always a divisor, so just count it and start looping from 2
- Just loop up to the square root of N, and count *both* the divisors you found (e.g., 4 is a divisor of 100, so `100//4` = 25 is a divisor too); but remember to avoid counting the square root twice

```
def divisors(n):
    divsum = 1
    for i in range(2,int(sqrt(n))+1):
        d,m = divmod(n,i)
        if m == 0:
            divsum += i
            if i != d:
                divsum += n // i
    return divsum
```

To find the buddies:

- check if the sum of divisors of N is lower than `start` (and if so `continue`) *before* computing the second sum
- also check if the sum of divisors of N is lower than M (and if so `continue` as well)

```
def buddy(start,limit):
    for i in range(start, limit+1):
        sum1 = divisors(i)
        if start > sum1-1 or i > sum1:
            continue
        sum_minus1 = divisors(sum1 - 1)
        if i == (sum_minus1 - 1):
            return [i, sum1 - 1]
    else:
        return "Nothing"
```

Comment: `divsum += d`...

Comment: @KellyBundy, yes, of course :D